# React Native Web keeps removing `aspectRatio` property from style. How do I prevent thsi?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, react-native-web

I'm trying to get react native component to return a `View` with an `aspect-ratio: 4.3` using:

```js
const component = () => <View style={{aspectRatio: 4 /3}} >{Content}</View>
```

I've also tried:

```js
const component = () => <View style={{'aspect-ratio: 4 /3}} >{Content}</View>
```

In both cases the CSS property is removed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Just reading this but I think it should be:

```
const component = () => <View style={{aspectRatio: "4 /3"}} >{Content}</View>
```

(4/3 must be wrapped in quotes)